# Firestore get roots field of a document

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I do have a firestore database: [image: Firestore database]

What I want, is to get to the root of the field **"points/0/title"**. Is it possible somehow?

Comment: What do you mean by the root of the field? If you mean the document containing the point with that title, you could look into writing a [complex query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries), although I'm not sure if querying by a field of an object inside an array would be supported. It might be a better idea to create a new collection of points if you need to query them by ID, although that would also be more expensive.

Comment: Well what I want is to get to the title which is inside field "0" and that is inside field "points". All I need is to get to that title field and the string which is inside that field somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you mentioned in your last comment, you can traverse a document as you would any other `Map` or dictionary object. The Firestore documentation for [Getting documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) is a good place to start. As for your nested field, if you would like to get the `Title` value, you could do it this way, by traversing the dictionary into the `points` array, then traversing the nested dictionary to the `Title` value:

```js
const docRef = doc(firestoreDB, "innerArray", "testDoc1");

  const getData = async () => {
    const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
    console.log(docSnap.data().points[0].title) //traversing the data obtained from a document
  }
```

This outputs `foo`, which is the value for `Title` in my test document.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked.